# I have an issue with coding this section of my project

Tags: python, time

i am trying to implement a piece of code that waits for a certain time before allowing a user to do something

i've been using help from the Internet and a coding book that i have

```
start=time.strftime("%H:%M")
if time.strftime("%H:%M")==("start"+"1%M"):
    print("done")
```

i would like the output to force a player to wait for some time then be able to carry on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `time.sleep(num_seconds)` command:

```
import time
...
# do some things
time.sleep(5)  # wait for 5 seconds doing nothing
# continue doing other things
```